# Trim a specific string

Tags: vb.net, trim

I am manipulating strings.
I want the output string to be only between 2 specific characters (`=` and `o`)

I can do this by repeat this twice:

```
For f = 1 To Len(line5)
    If Mid(line5, f, 1) = "=" Then
        line5 = Mid(line5, f, Len(line5) - f + 1)
        line5 = line5_out
    End If
```

One time for `=` and one for `o`

Is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: `Dim output As String = input.Split(New Char() {"="c, "o"c}).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: It works! But how do i avoid the first occurence to be the output? 
There is a "o" char before what i want

Comment: If you have a logic to discriminate between identical letters then apply it. If you have none, you have probably chosen the wrong identifier. On the other hand, if you have a single string to evaluate and these are the conditions, you can use `Dim output As String = Join(input.Split(New Char() {"="c, "o"c}).Skip(1).Take(2).ToArray, "")`

Comment: Yes it's just 1 string if have to evaluate
It worked as charm 
Thank You!

Comment: @AndréPortugal - Try `Regex.Match(text, "\=(.*?)o").Groups(1).Value` and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it, the "best" way depends on what exactly you need.
Besides those comments, here are two more ways to do it:

```
'Delete everything behind o and infront of =
YourString = YourString.Remove(YourString.LastIndexOf("o") + 1, YourString.Length - YourString.LastIndexOf("o") - 1).Remove(0, YourString.IndexOf("="))

'Get part of string between = and o
YourString = YourString.Substring(IndexOf("="), YourString.LastIndexOf("o") + 1 - YourString.IndexOf("="))
```